# Azure diagnostics multiple AppDomain issues

Tags: azure, appdomain, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I've bumped into a following problem with Azure Diagnostic Monitor:
When I create a new AppDomain in OnStart() event in WorkerRole entry point the diagnostics works only in the parent AppDomain. I've tried initializing Diagnostics Monitor in the child AppDomain but it doesn't help. (Traces are collected only from the parent domain)

Example repro code:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
        InitializeDiagnostics();
        Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole1 entry point called", "Information");

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Parent domain working", "Information");
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
        InitializeDiagnostics();

        var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        setup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
        var newDomain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewApplicationDomain",null, setup);
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => !x.GlobalAssemblyCache))
        {
            newDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
        }
        newDomain.Load(typeof (Worker).Assembly.FullName);
        var worker =  newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(this.GetType().Assembly.FullName, typeof (Worker).FullName) as Worker;
        worker.DoWork();


        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public void InitializeDiagnostics()
    {
        var roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = new RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"),
                                                                              RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
                                                                              RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance
                                                                                            .Role.Name,
                                                                              RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);
        var dmc = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();

        var dictionaryConfiguration = new DirectoryConfiguration();
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", dmc);
    }
}

public class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void DoWork()
    {


        new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Trace.TraceInformation(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + " Worker working...", "Information");
                }

            }).Start();
    }
}
```

}

App config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
           <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
           </listeners>
       </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Expected output:
Lots of logged messages:
"{Domain Name} Wokrer working..."
Some
"Parent domain working"

Actual output:
"Parent domain working"

I'm using Azure SDK 2.0. Have any of you came across a similar issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally solved it. Upgrading Azure SDK to 2.3 did the thing... It's interesting that messages still doesn't appear in Compute emulator console, but after upgrade they are correctly logged to WADLog table.